# Is inequality between population samples guaranteed?

Tags: statistics

This is a genuine mathematical inquiry. Depending on its assessment it has many predictions. Some of these would be bad for society. On the other hand it would be scientifically important and useful to society in other ways. From homelessness, to car accidents, to so forth.

The proposal is

> Between any two population samples, unless they are the same sample, the quotient of the distributions becomes very large or very small at the tail ends.

I am specifically requesting an analysis of this claim which can either strengthen or debunk its validity. Equally valid is successfully attacking the reasoning which leads to this proposal. Acceptable is a good reference(s).

To prove this in the ideal case only use the normal distribution is used. This is why this inquiry is within scientific reason.

Supposing two samples have respective statistical distributions $A(x) = \sqrt{(\alpha / \pi)} e^{-\alpha(x+\beta)^2}$ and $B(x) = \sqrt{(\alpha'/\pi)}e^{-\alpha'(x+\beta')^2}$.

If $\alpha' = \alpha + \Delta \alpha$ and $\beta' = \beta + \Delta \beta$ then

$$
\frac{A(x)}{B(x)} = \sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{\alpha + \Delta \alpha}}\exp{\Big(x^2\Delta\alpha + 2(\alpha\Delta\beta +\beta \Delta \alpha + \Delta \alpha \Delta \beta)x + \alpha'\beta'^2-\alpha \beta^2\Big)}
$$

For small $\Delta \alpha$ or $\Delta \beta$ this is nearly 1 around the origin, but is an exponential raised to a square. It will increase or decrease extremely rapidly in the left and right directions. If $\Delta \alpha$ and $\Delta \beta$ are sufficiently small, this makes our proposal null as the ratio is nearly 1 for all values that matter. But I suspect this is level of equality is not generally the case in real life and might not even be humanly possible to create. For larger values this inequality would be amplified.

An important point is that this demonstrates why the tail ends of the distribution are unreliable and unrepresentative as a sample for the entire distribution. However everyone in their area are in the tail ends of their own distribution. This makes getting samples harder. Researchers often sample students, but in light of this may be unreasonable and innaccurate.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SE. Do you mean, "is this a mathematical reason for the lack of women in academic Physics?", say? The reason would be that people are complicated and don't follow statistical distributions quite so nicely and the underlying reasons are often quite insidious. It may be part of it though. You may want to formalise what you are asking.

Comment: @JonnyBoy ??? How does that answer Stuart's comment?

Comment: Please limit the number of edits. Some editing is fine; too many can be a problem as every edit "activates" the question and thus causes noise.

Comment: Stuart's comment handwaves to his favor because of his politics, not science. But his comment doesn't make sense. Plenty of women go into science. This would be relevant to the most extreme divisons which is a tiny minority. Quid, edits were because politics interfers with mathematical logic as demonstrated.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with much of what you have to say, partly on grounds of personal opinion and partly because you are stating mathematical propositions without proof.

There is one possibly related *fact* that may be of
interest. If 1/3 of the population of a city belongs
to group A and 2/3 belong to group B, suppose we choose
75 people at random.

The probability that *exactly* 25 of them will be from group A is determined by the binomial
distribution. If $X$ is the number of A's chosen out of $75,$ then $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(75, 1/3)$ and
$$P(X = 25) = {75 \choose 25}\left(\frac 1 3\right)^{25} 
\left(\frac 2 3\right)^{75} = 0.0973.$$

```
dbinom(25, 75, 1/3)
[1] 0.09734124
```

So if you're looking for the sample proportion to be *exactly* the same as the population proportion, you will seldom see that. [It turns out that $\{X=25\}$ is the *most likely result*, but there are too many competing results for the most likely result to be hugely likely.]

However, the probability of being within five of $25$ is $P(20 \le X \le 30) = 0.8227.$

```
sum(dbinom(20:30, 75, 1/3))
[1] 0.8227381
diff(pbinom(c(19,30), 75, 1/3))
[1] 0.8227381
```

[image]

*Addendum:* Here is another case of what might be called 'systematic unfairness'. Four equally talented people play 12 games of Monopoly. You might think that would usually result in about three wins for each person. But in such 12-game 'tournaments' the mean number of games won by the most successful of the four is about 5.6 games.
(Least successful about 0.83.) Here is a simulation of 100,000 12-game tournaments.

```
w = replicate( 10^5, 
    max(rowSums(rmultinom(12, 1:4, rep(1:4)))) )
mean(w)
## 5.57715
```

Comment: One more thing... Sometimes even when everybody has the same chance of success, most people will have a win-loss record that is way ahead or way behind. This is the essence of Feller's arc-sine law, discussed in his famous probability book. [This page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/362728/whats-the-intuition-for-a-beta-distribution-with-alpha-and-or-beta-less-than/362760#362760) demonstrates this fact using simulation.

Comment: I appreciate this. The question was edited for others. Getting a "random" sample seems difficult in light of the last paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving aside the intent-implications, here's a model, inspired on chess. Let's say that the "player strengh" in some competition is modeled by a random variable $X$ (in chess, it could be the [ELO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system)), its distribution be $f_X(x)$
(typically a Gaussian distribution, or perhaps a [logistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system#Most_accurate_distribution_model) one).

Given two random players $A ,B$ , let's assume that the probability of $A$ winning (let's discard draws) is given by some probability which is a (odd aroud $(0,\frac12)$ ) funcion of the strengh difference: $p = g(X_A-X_B)$ . Again, $g$ could typically be a Gaussian or logistic cumulative distribution function.

Now, assume we have two different populations, with similar but not identical average strengh, e.g. $f_{X_A}(x)=f_{X_B}(x-\epsilon)$  (population $A$ is slightly stronger).

The OP is interested (I think) in showing that, under these conditions, for some typical/reasonable distributions, the advantage for population $A$ (its expected winning rate) is small if we pick a random player from each population, assuming $\epsilon$ is small. But that the advantage dramatically increases if we pick the random players from the upper percentiles.

Comment: That is correct. Also on the left end, but this time $B$ might win. One thing, you did a shift and set $\Delta \alpha = 0$ which supposedly weakens the increased advantage.